# Swift 2.1 Core Data - Pre-populating data with setValue() only persists the last one

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm working on an app that has Category entity that needs to have 4 default records pre-populated on launch.

I've looked at bundling my app with sqlite or csv file for preloading data, but since it's only 4 records I decided to inject the default values at runtime with a condition to execute only once.

The issue I'm facing is that with the following code block, I can only persist the last record `Drink`. I guess they overwrite themselves as it moves to next `setValue()`. How can I make sure to persist all records on the same attribute?

```
    do {
        let result = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)
        print(result.count)
        if result.count == 0 {

            //Pre-populate recipe categories
            let entityCategory = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("RecipeCategory", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)
            let newCategory = NSManagedObject(entity: entityCategory!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)

            newCategory.setValue("Main", forKey: "name")
            newCategory.setValue("Side", forKey: "name")
            newCategory.setValue("Dessert", forKey: "name")
            newCategory.setValue("Drink", forKey: "name")

            do {
                try newCategory.managedObjectContext?.save()
            } catch {
                let saveError = error as NSError
                print(saveError)
            }

        }
    } catch {
        print("Error fetching data")
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not creating a new `newCategory` each time you set one up. Try doing this instead:

```
let categories = ["Main", "Side", "Dessert", "Drink"]
for category in categories {
    let newCategory = NSManagedObject(entity: entityCategory!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)
    newCategory.setValue(category, forKey: "name")
}

do {
            try self.managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            let saveError = error as NSError
            print(saveError)
        }
```

Comment: Is there a way to ensure they are inserted in the same order as specified? I've tested it a few times and found that they are persisted in random order.

Comment: CoreData doesn't discriminate with storing values in order. All fetches will return a random ordering - you have to sort in some way to get ordered data.